# How can I select only one row in a table(grid)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, kendo-grid

I have a grid that I used to Selection inside(https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/grid/selection/).I actually have an array of data for example:

```
[{title:'test' ,id:1 ,selected :false}
 {title:'test2' ,id:2 ,selected :false}
 {title:'test2' ,id:3 ,selected :false}]
```

With this method, when the user clicks on a line, it (selected) becomes true:

```
  selectionChange = (event) => {
        const data = this.state.items.map(item=>{
            if(item.Id === event.dataItem.Id){
                item.selected = !event.dataItem.selected;
            }
            return item;
        });    
    }
```

In this case, the user can select any of the rows, but I want to be able to select only one row.....
What I want is for only one line to be selected.In fact, whatever line is selected, the other lines will be `selected :false`

Comment: ` if(item.Id === event.dataItem.Id){
                item.selected = !event.dataItem.selected;
            }`  afte this if condition, add item.selected = false; and add a rerun false inside the if condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way is to set all the items=> selected as false, and true to the only matching item.

Here if the item is selected, then it will change to false and all the other as false, if the item is not selected, then will change to true and all the other selected as false.

```
   const data = this.state.data.map(item=>{         
        if(item.ProductID === event.dataItem.ProductID){
            item.selected = !event.dataItem.selected;
            return item;
        }
       item.selected = false;
        return item;
    });
```

See the updated fiddle
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7wmlfp?file=app/main.jsx

Comment: @zahrazamani you are welcome..and thanks for accepting my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
selectionChange = (event) => {
    const data = this.state.items.map(item =>{
        item.selected = item.Id === event.dataItem.Id;
        
        return item;
    });
}
```